# Avoiding loops with Numpy arrays

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

A piece of equipment outputs a heatmap with a scale bar as an image, but has no option to the save the data as a .csv or something that can easily be imported into Python for analysis.

I have used PIL to pull in the image, then create an array of the heatmap, **frame1**, with dimensions 680, 900, 3 (an XY array with the 3 RGB values for each pixel). I then made an array from the scalebar, **scale1**, with dimensions 254, 3 (a line with the 3 RGB values for each point on the scale). To relate this to the actual scale values I create a linear space scaleval = np.linspace(maxval,minval, 254), where maxval and minval are the max and min of the scalebar, which I transcribe from the image.

I want to match each pixel in **frame1** to its closest colour match in **scale1**, and then store the corresponding scale value from **scaleval** into a dataframe **df**. In terms of for loops, what I want to do is:

```
# function returning the distance between two RGB values
def distance(c1, c2):
    (r1,g1,b1) = c1
    (r2,g2,b2) = c2
    return math.sqrt((r1 - r2)**2 + (g1 - g2) ** 2 + (b1 - b2) **2)

#cycle through columns in frame1
for j in range(frame1.shape[1]):
    
    #cycle through rows in frame1
    for k in range(frame1.shape[0]):
    
        # create empty list for the distances between the selected pixel and the values in scale1
        distances = []

        # cycle through scale1 creating list of distances with current pixel
        for i in range(len(scale1)):
            distances.append(distance(scale1[i], frame1[k,j,:]))
        
        # find the index position of the minimum value, and store the scale value to a dataframe in the current XY position
        distarr = np.asarray(distances)
        idx = distarr.argmin()
        df.loc[k,j] = scaleval[idx]
    print("Column " + str(j+1) + " completed")
```

However this would be quite slow. Any advice on how to avoid using for loops here?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone with a similar problem finds this while searching later:

I was able to vectorise the inner-most loop. The function *cdist* in Scipy allows you to generate a list of distances between one point and an array of points without iterating.

So this portion:

```
        distances = []

        # cycle through scale1 creating list of distances with current pixel
        for i in range(len(scale1)):
            distances.append(distance(scale1[i], frame1[k,j,:]))
        
        # find the index position of the minimum value, and store the scale value to a dataframe in the current XY position
        distarr = np.asarray(distances)
        idx = distarr.argmin()
        df.loc[k,j] = scaleval[idx]
```

became

```
            # create list of distances from current pixel to values in scale1 and store index of minimum distance
            idx = cdist([frame1[k,j,:]],scale1).argmin()
            df.loc[k,j] = scaleval[idx]
```

While there are still two for loops iterating through each pixel in **frame1**, the above change cut the run time to less than a third of what it was.